# Allow automake to generate optional compile rules

Tags: makefile, automake

I have made changes to a program which are part of a much larger project which use the Intel Performance Primitives. It turns out my recent changes use calls which are only available on the newest version of IPP, while a number of the users still use older versions. The program in question is not essential, so I want make it optional rather than back porting to the oldest versions of IPP (IPP has had a lot of API changes over the years).

We use automake/autoconf for generation of Makefiles. Ideally my particular program (single source file in C) would not be compiled by default, unless someone specifically runs "make myprog".

Is there a way to do this or do I have to support a "--with-myprog" option for the configure script?

The Makefile.am currently has (I think this is all that is relevant)

```
bin_PROGRAMS = \
    stripVDIF \
    {snip}
    generateVDIF 

generateVDIF_SOURCES = \
    generateVDIF.c

generateVDIF_LDADD = $(IPP_LIBS) $(LDADD)
```

My program is generateVDIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want it to be installed you can simply declared it as `EXTRA_PROGRAMS` rather than `bin_PROGRAMS` and that should do exactly what you want (only works with `make myprog`).

If you want it to be installed, you'll have to use `AC_ARG_WITH` and `AM_CONDITIONAL` in `configure.ac` and then have something like

```
bin_PROGRAMS = ....

if ENABLE_MYPROG
  bin_PROGRAMS += myprog
endif
```

and the rest remains the same.

Comment: The EXTRA_PRORGRAMS does exactly what I requested. Note that check_PROGRAMS seems to do the same. I have realised however the lack of an install option is a pain, so have added a --with-myprog option to the configure.ac.

Comment: `check_PROGRAMS` are built during `make check` and `make distcheck`, which are the "test" options (and one of the few prefixes that are not otherwise installed). `EXTRA_` prefix are meant for optional and not installed.

Answer (score 0):

The *right* way to do this is to place the build of your optional
program under the control of a `./configure` option, so that `./configure`
can manage it appropriately. See e.g. [how to add configure options](https://autotools.io/autoconf/arguments.html)

If that sounds too much like hard work you could exploit the fact that 
additional `make` code within a `Makefile.am` is simply passed through to the
generated `Makefile`.

So, e.g. if the following is the `Makefile.am` for target `foo`:

```
EXTRA_DIST = README 
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c
```

and you want to add an unmanaged target `bar`, a program built from `bar.c`,
then you can extend the `Makefile.am` to:

```
EXTRA_DIST = README bar.c
bin_PROGRAMS = foo
foo_SOURCES = foo.c

bar: bar.o
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -o$@ $< $(LDLIBS)
```

The autotooled package will then support `make bar`, and you could document this fact
for the user, with the appropriate caveats - notably including the absence of the usual autotooled `install` and `uninstall`.

Obviously, this shortcut would detract from a knowledgeable user's impression
of your professional chops.

Comment: While I can see what you are trying to achieve here, I could not get this to work as the "manual" make line did not include various other dependencies needed for compiling. I;m sure it could be made to work,  but Diego's solution achieves the same with no fuss.